# What does exactly "Re-root System (SuperSU)" do to your phone in Philz Touch Recovery?

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, selinux

I tried to manually root my phone via pushing a proper su binary to /system/bin and /system/xbin.  I was able to push them via adb in recovery, which is a root one (idk why). Once inside my phone, I chmodded 755 both of them and typed `su --install` and `su --daemon&`. After that, I tried to `setenforce 0`.

All seemed to work, but when I rebooted, I wasn't rooted. So I returned to recovery, used the "re-root" option and it worked.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/PhilZ-cwm6/philz_touch_cwm6https://github.com/PhilZ-cwm6/philz_touch_cwm6?files=1) available on GitHub, the recovery performs a whole bunch of operations aside from simply launching the daemon in background, copying the **su** binary to **/system/xbin** and changing its permissions. As can be understood by examining [this install-su script](https://github.com/PhilZ-cwm6/philz_touch_cwm6/blob/cm-11.0/su/supersu/install-su.sh), what the recovery does, is to initially perform a cleanup operation for root manager apps that may have already been installed.

After that, the operation of copying the relevant files, namely, the **su** binary (which is called anytime you request root privileges), the **99SuperSUDaemon** (which execution depends upon **init.d**), a customized **install-recovery.sh** (to force the daemon to be executed on Jelly Bean) and **SuperSU.apk** (the root manager).

After this phase, the script uses the previously defined functions **set_perm** (which combines **chmod** and chown, and serves to define ownership and permissions) and **ch_con** (which marks the files as system ones). The latter is probably the cause of your manual procedure's malfunction: you didn't change the context of the files you pushed, so they weren't recognized as system files.